# putting the detected face into an image and display in another window in opencv using python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

i'm new to image processing and opencv, but so far the easy to understand functions and good documentation have enabled me to try out and understand upto some level code like facedetection etc.

Now when i detect the faces in the webcam video stream, the program draws a square around the face. Now i want that much area of the image, in the square around the face, to be created as an another image. From what i've been doing, i'm getting a rectangular area of the image in which the face is not even present.

i've used the cv.GetSubRect() and understood its use. Like for eg:

```
img=cv.LoadImage("C:\opencv\me.jpg")
sub=cv.GetSubRect(img, (700,525,200,119))
cv.NamedWindow("result",1)
cv.ShowImage("result",sub)
```

- gives me the cropped picture of my eye.

But i can't get the face in my face and eye detection program.
Here's what i've done:

```
min_size = (17,17)
        #max_size = (30,30)

        image_scale = 2
        haar_scale = 2

        min_neighbors = 2
        haar_flags = 0

        # Allocate the temporary images
        gray = cv.CreateImage((image.width, image.height), 8, 1)
        smallImage = cv.CreateImage((cv.Round(image.width / image_scale),cv.Round (image.height / image_scale)), 8 ,1)
        #eyeregion = cv.CreateImage((cv.Round(image.width / image_scale),cv.Round (image.height / image_scale)), 8 ,1)
        #cv.ShowImage("smallImage",smallImage)

        # Convert color input image to grayscale
        cv.CvtColor(image, gray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

        # Scale input image for faster processing
        cv.Resize(gray, smallImage, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR)

        # Equalize the histogram
        cv.EqualizeHist(smallImage, smallImage)

        # Detect the faces
        faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(smallImage, faceCascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0),
        haar_scale, min_neighbors, haar_flags, min_size)
        #, max_size)

# If faces are found
        if faces:
                for ((x, y, w, h), n) in faces:
                # the input to cv.HaarDetectObjects was resized, so scale the
                # bounding box of each face and convert it to two CvPoints
                        pt1 = (int(x * image_scale), int(y * image_scale))
                        pt2 = (int((x + w) * image_scale), int((y + h) * image_scale))
                        cv.Rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, cv.RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 4, 0)
                        face_region = cv.GetSubRect(image,(x,int(y + (h/4)),w,int(h/2)))
                        cv.ShowImage("face",face_region)


 cv.SetImageROI(image, (pt1[0],
                        pt1[1],
                        pt2[0] - pt1[0],
                        int((pt2[1] - pt1[1]) * 0.7)))
                eyes = cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, eyeCascade,
                cv.CreateMemStorage(0),
                eyes_haar_scale, eyes_min_neighbors,
                eyes_haar_flags, eyes_min_size)    

            if eyes:
                    # For each eye found
                    for eye in eyes:

                            eye[0][0],eye[0][1] are x,y co-ordinates of the top-left corner of detected eye
                            eye[0][2],eye[0][3] are the width and height of the cvRect of the detected eye region (i mean c'mon, that can be made out from the for loop of the face detection)
                            # Draw a rectangle around the eye


                            ept1 = (eye[0][0],eye[0][1])
                            ept2 = ((eye[0][0]+eye[0][2]),(eye[0][1]+eye[0][3]))

                            cv.Rectangle(image,ept1,ept2,cv.RGB(0,0,255),1,8,0) # This is working.. 


                            ea = ept1[0]
                            eb = ept1[1]
                            ec = (ept2[0]-ept1[0])
                            ed = (ept2[1]-ept1[1])

                            # i've tried multiplying with image_scale to get the eye region within
                            # the window of eye but still i'm getting just a top-left area of the 
                            # image, top-left to my head. It does make sense to multiply with image_scale right?




                            eyeregion=cv.GetSubRect(image, (ea,eb,ec,ed))
                            cv.ShowImage("eye",eyeregion)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code is from OpenCV/samples/Python. There is a small mistake in the arguments you have given for the co-ordinates inside cv.GetSubRect. Please replace last two lines of above program with following:

```
a=pt1[0]
b=pt1[1]
c=pt2[0]-pt1[0]
d=pt2[1]-pt1[1]
face_region = cv.GetSubRect(image,(a,b,c,d))
cv.ShowImage("face",face_region)
```

Make sure, you have no false detection or multiple detection.

Comment: sorry for replying so late.
my internet connection was cut-off because of some bill payment discrepancies.
Anyways, what i've understood is that cv.Rectangle draws a rectangle with two given points diagonally opposite, and cv.GetSubRect takes a cvRect form of rectangle dimensions (which is just a top-left corner co-ordinates with width and height = x,y,w,h).

So basically from pt2 and pt1 you calculated the w,h which would be c and d respectively. and used them in the cv.GetSubRect function.

Comment: Now i'm having problems in getting the eye region. I've added the code in the main post

Comment: Please specify what is problem? OpenCV sample for facedetection also has other features like eye detection, mouth detection etc. Try that. And instead of comments, better ask as a new question.

Comment: The problem is related to this question, and i'm not sure it would be allowed to ask as another question.
I just want the eyes to be extracted just like the face, like you did in your code. I've appended the eye extraction code and please see if that has any bugs, because i'm not getting the eyes.

Comment: Do you want both eyes in different windows or in a single window?

Comment: [Here is the full code](http://pastebin.com/AyuHrtaB). But it is not optimised. Just gives you what you wanted. Optimize it yourself.

Comment: thank you, so i just had to get the eye_region from face_region. i changed that one thing, i got the eyes in "eye" NamedWindow

Comment: But then further down i looked and found what did to get both the eyes separately and display by 2 methods (and i swear i never would have thought that both eyes are returned! i thought just like faces, the best result is returned. I had my doubts when i printed 'eye' and got a lot of variation in the co-ordinates between successive detections)

So a BIG thank you for unveiling that, i thought i might have had to apply some complex technique to get both eyes. Hehe. Thanks again.

Comment: And now that i implemented the first method to get the left and right eyes displayed in a different window, the code runs but for a few seconds only, and then i get the error log:
"IndexError: list index out of range" for cv.ShowImage(eyes_list[i],eyeregion)

Now i understand since there are 2 eyes, i will iterate from 0 to 1, then back to 0 before "if eyes" for every detection of the two eyes.
So how can it possibly run out of range?! if increment part of i was done before the cv.ShowImage(eyes_lists[i],eyeregion) than it would have been logical.

Comment: The code with the error log can be found here:
[link](http://pastebin.com/6st4vhQs)

Comment: doing : `print "\n Value of i: ",i` and i found out that after 10-15 seconds of running, i = 2 !

Comment: Okay!! sorry for so many comments!! Simple solution: i put :
`if i>1:
    i=0
`

and the code's working like a boss! :) 
again, thank you sir for all the time and help so far

Comment: But I can't still figure out why did it increment upto 2, when it so far just oscillated between 0 and 1 ?
Can you help me?

Comment: The code works fine for me for static images ( i didn't test it for real time)

Comment: Well, the error you told is due to false detection of eyes(i>1). So to avoid unexpected termination of the program, make a condition that `if i==2:break` or `if i>1:break` after `i=i+1` line. So we restrict ourselves to first two detected objects (ie eyes)only. But the problem is that we can't be sure first two detected ones are the eyes. May be, that first one is the false one, and second,third are the eyes. Don't ask here, how to isolate eyes from false detections.  That is different topic and ask seperate question. Until that , above solution is sufficient..

Comment: wait a minute, **second,third are the eyes.** ? But `eyes[][][]` has only 2 2D arrays, so how can a third eye be returned from cv.HaarDetectObjects?

Comment: Some times a third object is also detected as eye. If you want to see that, print all eyes detected. Some times 3 arrays are detected, ie third false object. I told you if you have still doubts, ask it as seperate question. Copy your code there.

Comment: and please drop some hints about the optimization. i'm not an expert programmer :)